# Difference between message headers: Content-Type: charset="UTF-8" and Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Tags: email, smtp

I had received some mail message, but I was confused with these headers:

```
Content-Type: text/plain;
    format=flowed;
    charset="UTF-8";
    reply-type=response
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

If `Content-Type: charset="UTF-8"` is already specified, so why we need `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can also have:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

The charset is independent of the content encoding.

Comment: Now I got it - [RFC1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html) says: "The distinction between the Content-Transfer-Encoding values of "binary," "8bit," etc. may seem unimportant, in that all of them really mean "none" -- that is, there has been no encoding of the data for transport. However, clear labeling will be of enormous value to gateways between future mail transport systems with differing capabilities in transporting data that do not meet the restrictions of RFC 821 transport."

Comment: I think the answer is not right. Charset is a legacy term. charset here means encoding. See XML which is more up to date witth that `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` .

Comment: The Content-Transfer-Encoding is limited to `7bit`, `8bit`, `quoted-printable` and `base64`. None of those specify a *character* encoding. A *character* encoding would be `UTF-8`, `iso-8859-1`, `iso-2022-jp`, `euc-kr`, `koi8-r`, etc.